Updating Microsoft Teams Chats and Managing Attachments via Microsoft Graph API in C# .NET6 with Application level permission
I want to update Microsoft Teams Chats (one-on-one / Channel) programmatically via C# .NET6. Additionally, I want to download and delete attachments with Application level permission.
The Microsoft Graph API has an "Update chatMessage" section.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
Can someone please confirm if we can update/delete chat messages and delete and download attachments via the Graph API?
If yes, could you provide a sample code?
Thank you.

I have below chat message with attachments file sent to user named 'Sri' in MS Teams:

Initially, register one application and add API permissions of Delegated type by granting consent like this:

While using Interactive flow, make sure to enable public client flow and add redirect URI in "Mobile and Desktop applications" platform:

Now, make use of below sample C# code that downloads chat message attachment to specified path after successful authentication:
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors;
using System.Text;

namespace DownloadFile
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var scopes = new[] { "User.Read", "Chat.ReadWrite", "Files.Read" };
            var tenantId = "tenantId";
            var clientId = "appId";
            var options = new InteractiveBrowserCredentialOptions
            {
                TenantId = tenantId,
                ClientId = clientId,
                AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
                RedirectUri = new Uri("http://localhost"),
            };
            var interactiveCredential = new InteractiveBrowserCredential(options);

            var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(interactiveCredential, scopes);

            try
            {
                var chatId = "chatId";
                var messageId = "messageId";

                var message = await graphClient.Me.Chats[chatId].Messages[messageId].GetAsync();
                Console.WriteLine($"Message Content: {message.Body.Content}");

                var attachment = message.Attachments[0];
                Console.WriteLine($"Attachment Name: {attachment.Name}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Attachment URL: {attachment.ContentUrl}");
                var base64Url = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(attachment.ContentUrl));

                // Convert to unpadded base64url format
                base64Url = base64Url.TrimEnd('=').Replace('/', '_').Replace('+', '-');
                var encodedUrl = $"u!{base64Url}";
                var path = @"C:\Users\xxxx\Downloads\Folder1";
                var filePath = Path.Combine(path, attachment.Name);
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path);

                // Get the file using the OneDrive sharing link
                var driveItem = await graphClient.Shares[encodedUrl].DriveItem.GetAsync();

                var downloadUrl = driveItem.AdditionalData["@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl"]?.ToString();
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(downloadUrl))
                {
                    throw new Exception("Unable to get the download URL.");
                }

                var httpClient = new HttpClient();
                var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(downloadUrl);

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
                    await File.WriteAllBytesAsync(filePath, content);
                    Console.WriteLine($"\nAttachment downloaded successfully at: {filePath}");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Failed to download attachment. Status code: {response.StatusCode}");
                    var errorContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    Console.WriteLine($"Error details: {errorContent}");
                }
            }
            catch (ODataError odataError)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error Code: {odataError.Error.Code}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Error Message: {odataError.Error.Message}");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
    }
}

Response:

When I checked the specified path, chat message attachment downloaded successfully like this:

To update the chat message and delete the attachment, make use of below modified code:
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors;

namespace UpdateMsg
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var scopes = new[] { "User.Read", "Chat.ReadWrite", "Files.Read" };
            var tenantId = "tenantId";
            var clientId = "appId";
            var options = new InteractiveBrowserCredentialOptions
            {
                TenantId = tenantId,
                ClientId = clientId,
                AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
                RedirectUri = new Uri("http://localhost"),
            };
            var interactiveCredential = new InteractiveBrowserCredential(options);

            var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(interactiveCredential, scopes);

            try
            {
                var chatId = "chatId";
                var messageId = "messageId";

                var requestBody = new ChatMessage
                {
                    MessageType = ChatMessageType.Message,
                    Subject = null,
                    Summary = null,
                    Importance = ChatMessageImportance.Normal,
                    Locale = "en-us",
                    From = new ChatMessageFromIdentitySet
                    {
                        Application = null,
                        Device = null,
                        User = new Identity
                        {
                            Id = "userId",
                            DisplayName = "User",
                            AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>
                            {
                                {
                                     "userIdentityType" , "aadUser"
                                },
                             },
                        },
                        AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>
                     {
                        {
                        "conversation" , null
                         },
                      },
                    },
                    Body = new ItemBody
                    {
                        ContentType = BodyType.Text,
                        Content = "Attachment deleted", //Updated message
                    },
                    Attachments = new List<ChatMessageAttachment>
                    {
                    },
                    Mentions = new List<ChatMessageMention>
                    {
                    },
                    Reactions = new List<ChatMessageReaction>
                    {
                    },
                    MessageHistory = new List<ChatMessageHistoryItem>
                    {
                    },
                };

                var msg = await graphClient.Me.Chats[chatId].Messages[messageId].PatchAsync(requestBody);
                Console.WriteLine("Message updated");

            }
            catch (ODataError odataError)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error Code: {odataError.Error.Code}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Error Message: {odataError.Error.Message}");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
    }
}

Response:

To confirm that, I checked that same in MS Teams chat where attachment deleted and message updated like this:

Reference:
Update chatMessage - Microsoft Graph
UPDATE:
To do the same using application-level permissions, make below changes:
Replace graphClient.Me.Chats[chatId].Messages[messageId].GetAsync() method with graphClient.Chats[chatId].Messages[messageId].GetAsync().Result
Make sure to create Graph Client using client credentials flow auth provider by referring this MS Document.

My apologies, I skip to mention that I want these features with Application level permission. Can you please confirm the possibility with Application level permission

Hi Sridevi,
I wanted to let you know that I successfully used your code to download an attachment with application level permission. Although as you specified chat features are only available via delegated permission.
I made a couple of modifications to download files with Application Level Permission.
Here are the changes I made:
Instead of using the "me" keyword with the graphClient.Me.Chats[chatId].Messages[messageId].GetAsync() method, I used this : graphClient.Chats[chatId].Messages[messageId].GetAsync().Result.
GraphApiClient is created with Application level permission.

Please check the updated answer and let me know if any changes required
